# Правильная подборка количества слоев в сверточной нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Всех приветствую.

Такой вопрос:

К примеру, есть нейронка с 2 слоями свертки:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))



model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Но также я встречал нейронки и по 7 сверточных слоев.

Отсюда вопрос:

На что влияет количество слоев?

Как я понимаю, влияет именно на точность или же качество распознавания чего либо.

Но тогда почему бы не сделать, к примеру, 50 слоев сразу?

Как вообще подбирается количество слоев и количество нейронов в них?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы угадали - одна из очень популярных CNN архитектур - [ResNet50](https://www.kaggle.com/keras/resnet50/home) состоит из 50 скрытых слоев.

Также существуют [другие популярные сверточные сети](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/convnet-architectures/) с гораздо большим числом слоев, например `DenseNet-250` с 250-ю слоями.

Количество слоев влияет на сложность (абстрактность) образов рассматриваемых НС. На начальных слоях распознаются простые примитивы, например прямые под различными углами, дальше могут идти дуги, сектора и т.д. Чем глубже слой тем более сложные / абстрактные примитивы он рассматривает - например глаз или клюв, или если копнуть еще глубже - человек, птица или машина. Дальше можно, например, различать чем занят человек на картинке - сидит, лежит, едет на велосипеде, на скейте и т.д.

> Как вообще подбирается количество слоев и количество нейронов в них?

Это целое искусство - подобрать удачную архитектуру, которая будет:

1. хорошо обучаться
2. быстро обучаться
3. не переобучаться
4. будет стойкой к размытым / некачественным изображениям
5. сможет хорошо до-обучаться
   ...

На практике люди изучают последние теоретические и практические наработки и **очень много эксперементируют**